# Objective C - Catch exception raised from inside a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, try-catch, objective-c-blocks

I'm using the following code in app:

```
@try {
        if(!self.usernameField.text || [self.usernameField.text isEqualToString:@""])
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid value for username" format:@"Please enter your username."];

        if(!self.passwordField.text || [self.passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""])
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid value for password" format:@"Please enter your password."];


        [LoginManager
         userLogin:self.usernameField.text
         andPassword:self.passwordField.text
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {

             if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loginSuccessWithUserName:)]) {
                 [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(loginSuccessWithUserName:)withObject:self.usernameField.text];
             }

             [self dismissPopoverController];
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) {
             NSString* nsLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = [err.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion"];

             if(err.code == -1009) {

                 [NSException raise:@"No Internet connection" format:@"It appears you’re not connected to the internet, please configure connectivity."];
             }

             if([nsLocalizedRecoverySuggestion rangeOfString:@"Wrong username or password."].location != NSNotFound) {

                 [NSException raise:@"Invalid username or password" format:@"Your given username or password is incorrect"];
             }
             else {
                 [NSException raise:@"BSXLoginViewController" format:@"Error during login"];
             }
         }];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login error"
                                                       message:exception.description
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

However the exceptions raised in the failure block don't get catched in the catch section.
I kind of understand why it's logical, but i would like to know if there's a way to tell the block that the exceptions happening inside should be handled by the catch section i created.

Thanks for any help!

Sincerely, 
Zoli

Comment: You need move @try-@catch into fail block. Сause fail block may call with delay/

Comment: Alternatively, don't use Try/Catch for control flow within Objective-C. Exceptions are usually used for catching programmer errors. In your case you can handle the exceptional conditions within the block itself, rather than throwing it out to a different context.

Comment: I just don't want the app to have several exit points. So i don't want to force returns in my code. I prefer every function should have only one return point if works accordingly. If not, handle it as an exception (In this case an NSError).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this.   First of all, and I'm sure you'll get at least a comment from @bbum about this, `NSException` isn't intended in Objective-C for recoverable errors and propagating recoverable errors through code (see [Introduction to Exception Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html)).   Instead, the construct used in Objective-C is to use `NSException` basically for unrecoverable programming errors, and to use `NSError` objects for handing around recoverable errors.

However, you've got a bigger problem here in that the calls that you are making have block callbacks because they return before completing.   In this case, your exception handler is exited long before the exceptions are actually thrown.

In this case, I'd suggest removing the exceptions and handling the errors inside of the actual `failure:` block by dispatching to the main queue and presenting the `UIAlert` there.

Comment: I didn't know the difference, but you are very right! Thanks for pointing that out. Also that has become my solution.

Comment: @gaige no need.  You got it covered just fine!

Comment: Note also that you should use `NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey` instead of a hardcoded string

Answer (score 1):

Don't be fooled by the fact that your block is specified inline with other code. You cannot catch exceptions in the block in the outer (non-block) code because the code in the TRY block has already executed (and exited) and the block only executes in it's own scope.

A solution is to catch exceptions in the block.